# Covariant Taylor Series

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, differential-geometry, covariance

I am reading the following lecture notes of Avramidi 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255565392_Analytic_and_geometric_methods_for_heat_kernel_applications_in_finance

I want to understand the covariant taylor series part (page 87). Let $f$ be a scalar function on a Riemannian manifold. We have the Taylor series

$$f(x(t))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}t^n\left[\frac{d^n}{d\tau^{n}}f(x(\tau))\right]_{\tau=0}$$
Here $x(t)$ describes a geodesic from $x(0)=x'$ and $x(t)=x$. Now we have that $\frac{d}{d\tau}=\dot{x}(\tau)\nabla_{i}$ and the geodesic equation $\dot{x}^{i}\nabla_{i}\dot{x}^{j}=0$ ($\nabla$ is the Levi Cevita connection). Then he claims
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}t^n\dot{x}^{i_{1}}(0)...\dot{x}^{i_{n}}(0)[\nabla_{(i_{1}}...\nabla_{i_{n})}f](x')$$
The parantheses denote symmetrization. [...] denotes the value inside when $x\rightarrow x'$

Where does this symmetrization comes from? For me it is not necessary.

Comment: And this is a physics question how? This seems to be a pure math question.

Comment: I asked it on mathstackexchange: no answer. This is used in heat kernel expansions, very important in physics.

Comment: Link of mathstackexchange version: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1860440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is obvious: $$x^{i_{1}i_2,\cdots i_n}:= \dot{x}^{i_{1}}(0)...\dot{x}^{i_{n}}(0)$$ is completely symmetric, so that when computing a total contraction,  $$x^{i_{1}i_2,\cdots i_n} T_{(i_{1}...i_{n})}= x^{i_{1}i_2,\cdots i_n}T_{i_{1}...i_{n}}\:,$$
for every covariant tensor $T$ of order $n$, nomatter the symmetry properties of its indexes.

Comment: So we symetrize for convenience, right?

Comment: Yes, for pure convenience...

Comment: But actually it (your T)is not symmetric I think. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it is not symmetric, but only the symmetric part matters in the final result.

Comment: Is there not an extra $n!$ from symmetrization?

Comment: It depends on the definition of $(i_1,\cdots,i_n)$, I usually include $1/n!$ in it...

Comment: In the formula I posted, symmetrization includes $1/n!$, otherwise the formula would make no sense.